# Spring Security OAuth2: CORS preflight channel did not succeed

Tags: oauth, spring-boot, cors, jhipster, spring-security-oauth2

I was receiving this error while making a call to '/oauth/token' when I was making an HTTP call to the server instance running on my own system. I fixed this by creating a filter like this:

```
@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    if (httpServletRequest.getMethod() != "OPTIONS") {
      chain.doFilter(req, res);
    } else {
        // In case of HTTP OPTIONS method, just return the response
    }
}
```

I have added it as a filter in WebConfigurer:

```
private void initCORSFilter(ServletContext servletContext, EnumSet<DispatcherType> disps) {
    log.debug("Registering CORS Filter");
    FilterRegistration.Dynamic corsFilter = servletContext.addFilter("corsFilter", new SimpleCORSFilter());
    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    corsFilter.setInitParameters(parameters);
    corsFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(disps, true, "/*");
    corsFilter.setAsyncSupported(true);
}
```

I am getting this error in FireFox:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://182.176.221.94:9091/ams/oauth/token. (Reason: CORS preflight channel did not succeed).
```

In short I was making sure the the preflight OPTIONS call always gets a response to proceed ahead. This was working on my own system, but now that the server instance is deployed on a Linux server, I am again getting this issue. And I am getting this only on calling 'oauth/token', everything other call is working fine.

What can I possibly do to get rid of this. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Your filter does not need to be annotated with `@Component` and it should be mapped with adequate url pattern in `WebConfigurer` class like other filters used in JHipster.

Also your filter should not break the filter chain as it does for OPTIONS.  It's not consistent to allow OPTIONS method in header and then to not return the headers if you are processing an OPTIONS request.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please take a look. I have added the filter in WebConfigurer already. Removing the @Component attribute makes it stop working even on my local machine.

Comment: it works for me without @Component so something is wrong in your project

Comment: I added more details about inconsistency in your filter about OPTIONS

Comment: The reason why you don't need @Compoenent is because you already  instantiate it with new SimpleCORSFilter() in WebConfigurer.initCORSFilter(). If you put a breakpoint in debugger you should see that the filter constructore is called twice and if it's not then it's your app init in webConfigurer that fails.

Comment: I found the issue and posted it as the answer. I really appreciate your help and feedback, and will follow your advice to improve the things that I am doing wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using != comparison for `if (httpServletRequest.getMethod() != "OPTIONS"`. I changed it to `if (!httpServletRequest.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("OPTIONS"))` instead and it worked. This could have something to do with the fact that I tested on local machine while running the codebase but created a WAR file out of it and deployed on the server where it didn't work. I am not sure what exactly is the reason, but this fixed the issue.